# How to make a show hide of two textboxes using two radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, radio-button, show-hide

by clicking on radio buttons i need to show hide two text boxes. when i click on radio1 text box1 shows ..
i need to show text box2 on clicking radio button2 and hide the textbox1

please help me to solve with the below code

### Html

```
   <p>
      KYC<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="Show">
      Bank OTP<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="hide">
  </p>
  <div class="textd1">
     <p>Textbox #1 <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30"></p>
 </div>
 <div class="textd2">
 <p>Textbox #2 <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30">/p>
 </div>
```

### js

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".textd1").hide()
        $(".textd2").hide()
        $('[name=radio1]').on('change', function(){
            $('.textd1').toggle(this.value === 'Show');
        }) 
        $('[name=radio2]').on('change', function(){
            $('.textd2').toggle(this.value === 'Show');
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the `name` of radio buttons same so it forms a group and give it a single `event` of `click` and based on the value of the `radio` show or hide required textbox as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".textd1").hide()
  $(".textd2").hide()
  $('[name=radio]').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Show") {
      $('.textd1').show();
      $('.textd2').hide();
    } else {
      $('.textd1').hide();
      $('.textd2').show();
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  KYC
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="Show">Bank OTP
  <input type="radio" name="radio" value="hide">
</p>

<div class="textd1">
  <p>Textbox #1
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="text1" maxlength="30">
  </p>
</div>
<div class="textd2">
  <p>Textbox #2
    <input type="text" name="text2" id="text2" maxlength="30">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks its working.. hoW can i set both radio buttons unselected on load?

Comment: and How can i give a small animation to the textbox

Comment: @APJ instead of `hide` and `show` use `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` like `$('.textd1').fadeIn();$('.textd2').fadeOut();` and vice versa.. You can also provide time in milliseconds/string for `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` as `$('.textd1').fadeIn('200');$('.textd2').hide('fast');`

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".textd1").hide()
    $(".textd2").hide()
    $('#a').on('change', function(){
        $(".textd2").hide()
      $('.textd1').show();
    }) 
    $('#b').on('change', function(){
        $(".textd1").hide()
        $('.textd2').show()
    })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d1n4rg24/1/